# iMac late 2009, Screen mess up - black windows

Tags: macos, imac

Yesterday I was working on my iMac 27" Late 2009 with OS X Mavericks 10.9, suddenly Google Chrome's tabs started to flicker. I thought restart would stop this - but after the computer boot up again it was even worse.
The boot screen and System restore are looking fine (So i don't think the monitor hardware is the problem).
I even re-installed OS X again, but still no change.
Here is some images I took of my screen.
[image: Screenshot1] 
also, the login screen is even more messed up:
[image]

Please advice!! I don't know what to do!!!
Is it a known problem? any known solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem returned after 1 month, I took the computer to local Apple reseller (I don't have an Apple Store where I live at all) - the entire logic board replaced and the problem is now solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use following steps to address the problem.

I see that your background (desktop, the menu bar and the icons look fine) and it works fine in low resolution mode (system restore screen) lets do some testing:

- Start in safe mode (hold Shift) to eliminate 3d party applications (and resolution settings).
- Log in as different user to eliminate problems with your account.

If no problem, repair your user account using the cmd-r and password reset process (without resetting password, but repairing the ACL's)

- Plug in External Monitor to eliminate build in monitor.
- Reset PRAM Command (⌘)-Option-P-R
- Run Apple Hardware Test (hold D) to check for hardware problems.
  If AHT does not start it is probably on the CD that came with computer

Comment: Thank you a lot! My computer was on recovery mode for copying all the file using terminal before making any fix to prevent data loss. Today as I was trying to start apple hardware test (and failed - pressing d didn't got me into it). But somehow the display is all right again. I don't know of it was pressing the d during Boot or it was just time. Buy it now fully functioning! Thank you

Comment: Tell me which one worked for you? Some computers do not have the Hardware test installed. Sometimes the Safe mode fixes some problems.

Comment: I get a thank you but no cookies :(

Comment: The hardware test somehow fixed it...

Comment: That is all that counts, it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your images, this is either a graphics processor issue or a display issue. I highly suspect the former. *Either way, it is a hardware issue for which no online troubleshoot exists.*

To test, however, the next time it occurs, [take a screen shot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5775?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). If the distortion appears on your screenshot, then the problem is with your graphics processor and you to get your logic board replaced. If the distortion does not appear on the screenshot, then the issue is with your display and you need to get your display replaced.

Best of luck.